# Iptables port forwarding on Ubuntu (Docker)

Tags: ubuntu, iptables, port-forwarding

I have an Ubuntu Docker image running in Kubernetes and I'm trying to set up port forwarding to route requests coming in on port 5000 to a different destination and port (10.30.8.191:443). I installed iptables (not installed by default) and added the following rules:

```
iptables -A PREROUTING -t nat -p tcp --dport 5000 -j DNAT --to 10.30.8.191:443
iptables -A FORWARD -p tcp -d 10.30.8.191 --dport 443 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
```

I also verified `/proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward` is set to `1`. However, making a curl call to `https://127.0.0.1:5000` results in `connection refused`. I have verified that the destination ip `10.30.8.191` is directly accessible from this host.

Any ideas what I might be missing? I haven't specified an interface in my iptables rules, which to my understanding means the rules should apply to all existing interfaces. Is that not the case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Local originated packets don't pass through `nat/PREROUTING` chain. To make request to 127.0.0.1:5000 success you should add same `DNAT` rule into `nat/OUTPUT` chain:

```
iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT \
         -d 127.0.0.1 -p tcp --dport 5000 \
    -j DNAT --to 10.30.8.191:443
```

- It also requires the changing of `net.ipv4.conf.lo.route_localnet` variable:

```
sysclt -w net.ipv4.conf.lo.route_localnet=1
```

- Reply packets should pass through your ubuntu host, otherwise you get the routing triangle issue. To do it you should add `SNAT` rule:

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING \
         -d 10.30.8.191 -p tcp --dport 443 \
         -m conntrack --ctstate DNAT --ctorigdstport 5000 \
    -j MASQUERADE
```